# Replace lambdas by bold lambdas in a macro

Tags: bold, automation, greek

I am looking for a way to replace `\lambda` by `\bm\lambda` in some of my expressions. This is what I tried, without success:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{document}

    \def\MakeLambdaBold#1{\StrSubstitute{#1}{\lambda}{\bm\lambda}}
    $\MakeLambdaBold{\lambda}$

    \pretocmd{\lambda}{\bm}
    $\lambda$

\end{document}
```

Comment: The assignments `\let\svlambda\lambda` `\def\lambda{\bm\svlambda}` will make **all** lambdas bold.  But you haven't indicated how you would like to indicate which lambdas get bolded, when you use the words "some of my expressions"... The easiest way to make "some" of them bold is to just place `\bm` before the ones you desire as bold.  Alternately, you could define a macro to make bold lambdas.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The sample LaTeX code indicates that bers wants to define a command \MakeLambdaBold that takes the desired expression as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a pure TeX solution, rather than using those fancy packages?

```
\let\truelambda\lambda%
\def\makelambdabold#1{%
    \begingroup%
    \def\lambda{\bm{\truelambda}}%
    #1%
    \endgroup%
}
```

Edit: And sorry to sound a bit preachy, but let me also indicate the "right" thing to do, if it's not already too late. You should define commands that indicate the different things that lambda (or anything else) can mean in your document, even if they're represented by the same symbol. That way, if you decide to change notation later, you can just change one command rather than use the dodgy workaround we're discussing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It leads to `pdflatex` running endlessly, though, when I use it twice in the same environment, for example, like this: `$\makelambdabold{x} \makelambdabold{\lambda}$`. This is easily fixed by introducing extra `{` and `}` around the definition, so I will accept your answer as soon as it's edited. Regarding your comment, you are absolutely right. I only have one "thing" with name `\lambda` (printed non-bold), however, when using it in a vector subscript (such as `x_\lambda`) it needs to be printed bold as every vector (IEEE journal style).

Comment: ... or, as I just saw in Steven B. Segletes's answer, by moving the `\let` outside the macro. As his answer is slightly more elaborate and only minimally later, I accepted his answer, I hope that's OK.

Comment: I didn't read your answer before posting mine (or I wouldn't have posted) and I can't delete an accepted answer.  So I upvoted yours.  I am sorry about that.

Comment: I would suggest Jim takes my suggestion to move the `\let` outside the macro, and suggest @bers accepts Jim's answer instead of mine.  Then I will delete mine, since I didn't realize it was essentially a duplicate.

Comment: As you wish ... :)

Comment: `\begingroup` before `\def\lambda` and `\endgroup` after `#1` are in order. Maybe the OP wants to use just `\makelambdabold` in a formula, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone! @egreg is quite right; without begingroup/endgroup the command takes effect after it ought to, even within a formula.